# What characters can't come as the very last character of a url?

Tags: url, sanitization

I am trying to get all url links from a text in Python. Say this is the text:

```
Go to google.com, and then follow the instructions.
```

I can use `string.split()` and then check each word one by one. But, it will return `google.com,` (note the comma). I can get rid of the comma using another function, but what if it is `goole.com!` or `google.com.` or etc. Theoretically speaking, can we have a valid url like `www.website.com?` What characters can I safely remove from the end of a word, knowing that that character can't possibly be a part of a url?

Comment: If a character can appear in a trialing URL segment, it can appear as the last character. `google.com!` is invalid, however, `http://foo/when?(should).this,end`? .. anyway, there are a _plethora_ of regular expressions out there it extract URL; string.split is insufficient here with any sort of generalization.

Answer (score 0):

There is no correct answer to this.

As you noted, a URL can end with a `?`.  It can also end with an un-escaped `.` or `,` or `:` or `;`.

- `.` is an unreserved character so it doesn't ever need to be `%` escaped.
- The others are reserved, but (I think) they can all be used without escaping at the the end of a valid URL ... in some circumstances.  (And also in URLs that are not strictly spec conformant.)

However, while these endings are all possible, they are all unlikely; i.e. people who design web services / sites *typically* don't emit URLs.

So the answer for you will depend on how and where you are getting these URLs from, and what you intend to do with them.  Your stripping will necessarily be based on a heuristic (to be useful) ... so *adjust* your heuristics to give you the best results for your application.

---

Your `google.com` example is problematic for another reason.  It isn't a genuine URL at all because it doesn't have a protocol.  It is not even *meanigful* as a URI ... since `google.com` is unlikely to be resolvable relative to any absolute URI.   It is actually a DNS name.

Now DNS names often have corresponding URLs (e.g. `google.com` corresponds to `http://google.com` and `https://www.google.com` and a few other URLs) but that is not necessarily so.  And it is not possible to *reliably* distinguish between correctly inferred URLs and URLs that won't actually work if you try to resolve them.  (Even trying to connect to the URL won't always give the correct answer.)